# Admin authentication on a Windows XP machine on a network

Tags: windows-xp, authentication, local-area-network

This is something I'm curious about. There is a LAN consisting of Windows XP machines. There is an administrator account say admin-xyz which can be used to login to any of the machines on the network.
But, when I run pwdump to get the password hashes on a machine, I dont see the admin-xyz account. I am just curious as to how the authentication happens. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thank You.

Comment: is this 'admin-xyz' a domain admin account?

Comment: yes Dan, i think it is.So, in that case how does the authentication happen ?

Comment: Thats domain authentication, which authenticates against the domain controller.

Comment: Just keep in mind that using tools such as pwdump may not be permitted on a corporate network, where it's often considered to be security violation.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's only dumping the LOCAL hashes from the SAM, and you are looking for the domain admin account which is not stored locally.